# Why can't I submit a question in Russian?

Tags: bug, status-completed, unicode

According to [What language(s) should we use for the site?](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-languages-should-we-use-for-the-site) and 
[Question bodies in other languages](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/question-bodies-in-other-languages) it seems to have been agreed upon that questions in Russian are OK. However, it seems that the SE itself doesn't allow that. I tried to post a question in Russian with a Russian title and the system rejected it as "It does not meet our quality standards." I think it's because all characters were in cyrillic. Can anyone please comment on this?

In order to reproduce the problem, try to ask a question with the following title

> Заглавие на русском языке

and the following body

> Несмотря на то, что в мете было установлено, что вопросы можно задавать на русском, сам сайт не позволяет этого делать. Почему это так?

This wasn't my actual question, I just thought the rejection was due to Russian, so I made up this fake question that clearly reproduces the problem.

***Update:*** seems that the problem occurs only when the title is in Russian in its entirety.

***Update:*** I requested the feature at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136457/can-we-please-allow-russian-titles-in-russian-stackexchange-com

Comment: Yes, there is a kind of ["normalization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_normalization) of question titles used to do some kinds of checks. One of the steps in the normalization process is to remove "strange" or "foreign" characters. Sadly all Cyrillic characters fall into this category! I'm sure the process has been adapted for japanese.SE though so we expect it to be adapted for russian.SE too.

Comment: @hippietrail Maybe we should migrate this question to meta.stackexchange.com to get it done?

Comment: Yes either migrate or just ask another version of it over there tailored for the more general audience. But first see if something similar is already there.

Comment: As hippietrail notes, stuff posted on MSO should apply to the broader network not just a single site - posting this here was fine (we've just been lazy and missed it). Note that *as a rule* this [won't be done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118713/can-the-quality-filter-be-tweaked-or-disabled-for-non-so-sites) - but exceptions are made for sites that legitimately post with little or no English content.

Comment: btw, @hippietrail: in general, don't *migrate* stuff from per-site metas to MSO - as this example illustrates, there are lots of per-site topics that will either not apply, or apply differently in the context of the network as a whole. Tailoring for the general audience (and broader topic) is very much needed in those cases where a post has a legitimate need to reach that broader audience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our quality filter is a bit biased, to, uh, English. (:

I've turned it off here, so get to posting those Cyrillic characters!

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)